# Combine Fullname in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do you combine firstName, middleName and lastName in ES6?
What I do is `${firstName} ${middleName} ${lastName}`
But the problem there is a space in between if middleName is not there. Middle name is not always present

Comment: Tip: Ternary operator. Or forget templates and `[ ... ].filter(...).join(' ')`

Comment: `[firstName, middleName, lastName].filter(x => x).join(' ')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[firstName, middleName, lastName].filter(Boolean).join(" ")
```

should work just fine.

Since the empty string is falsy and `Boolean(x)` will compute the truthiness of `x`, `.filter(Boolean)` will drop it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using javascript template literals:

```js
const firstName = "John";
const lastName="Doe";
const middleName="middle";

const printFullName = (firstName, lastName, middleName) => {
   console.log(
     `${firstName}${middleName ? ` ${middleName}` : ''} ${lastName}`
   )
}

printFullName(firstName, lastName);
printFullName(firstName, lastName, middleName);
```

Comment: That is not what was asked. Try commenting out your `// const middleName="middle";`

Answer (score 0):

You can nest and use a ternary

```js
const firstName = "John"
const lastName="Doe"
console.log(
`${firstName} ${typeof middleName !== "undefined" ? `${middleName} ` : ''}${lastName}`
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first space between the first and middle name and handle it in the middle name itself example:

```
`${firstName}${middleName ? ' ' + middleName : ''} ${lastName}`
```

Comment: @mplungjan Why?

Comment: Now test. Your will get another error

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that middleName is always defined but may not have a value